# Pythonで可変関数の書き方を教えてください。

Tags: python

Pythonの勉強中です。

PHPでは可変関数と言うものがあります。

```
$a = 'Model_AAAA';
$instance = new $a();
```

上記のように書くとModel_AAAAと言うクラスのインスタンスが出来るのですが、
Pythonでこのような書き方はできますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec`を使えば任意の文字列を実行可能です．例えばphpの例とおなじようにできます。

```
a = 'Model_AAAA'
exec('instance = {}()'.format(a)) # "instance = Model_AAAA()"が実行される
```